# GET user endpoint always returns MY user data, regardless of ID in query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am querying the Microsoft Graph API to get OneDrive files, like:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/delta`

There is a `lastModifiedBy` facet in the `driveItem` resource returned, but it only contains a `displayName` and `id`. I need the user's email based on that ID.

So I tried the endpoint from [these docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get), which is:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}`

Specifically, I have tried things like:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/45aa3379f269b493`

But it always returns the exact same set of data (regardless of which `id` I pass in), which is the data from the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` endpoint.

My scopes are the following:

```
offline_access
files.read.all
user.read
user.readbasic.all
people.read
contacts.read
contacts.read.shared
```

Is there any reason that this endpoint is not returning the data for the specific user ID that I pass? Or is there an alternative way to get the user's email based on the information provided in `lastModifiedBy`?

Comment: Could you add the JSON from `v1.0/me/drive/root/delta`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT https://pastebin.com/mtJWjtqe

Comment: All of the files in that result set were late modified by you. I'm not sure what you are expecting but passing in that user `id` will result in the same as `/me`

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Yeah I guess I'm actually referring to the ID given in the permissions endpoint in the `invitation` facet. I was just assuming that if a shared file was edited by someone else, the `lastModifiedBy` would have a different user ID.

That does not affect my results though. I manually went to the graph explorer and punched in different IDs for the endpoint, but still got the results for `/me` every time. I was just trying to give some context with the first part of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the`JSON` you posted, I noticed your files have an `id` using the format `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx!xxx` (note the `!`). This tells me this is a personal Microsoft Account (MSA).

Since this is a Microsoft Account, there are no "users" beyond yourself. Graph will therefore disregard whatever `id` you provide and always return your own profile (`/me`). In order to use `/users` you need to be connected to an Azure Active Directory tenant.

You cannot pull profile information for other MSA/Outlook.com accounts. Were this supported it would introduce an unacceptable hole in MSA privacy/security.

Comment: So for personal accounts, is there no way to get the email of a user who last modified a file? Because the lastModifiedBy facet only returns displayName and id.

Comment: That is correct. Graph cannot pierce the vale of someone else's Microsoft Account to pull information.